# Нетипичное предложение

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

Как вам это предложение в плане пунктуации?

> У Пети были хорошие запасы: грибы, брусника, сухой паёк, сухари и много спичек; а у Петровича скудновато: несколько груш и стакан спирта.

**И формально, согласно пунктуационным правилам, всё нормально?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С пунктуацией всё в порядке.

**1) Точка с запятой**

§ 113. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения может стоять **точка с запятой,** особенно если его части значительно распространены и имеют внутри запятые (чаще при наличии союзов а, но, зато, же, тоже, также): Ужас сердце чует в этот краткий миг, который делит гул громовый на удары; а они гремят, и тучи разрываются, бросая золотые стрелы молний из рядов своих на землю (М. Г.); http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

**2) Двоеточие (или тире) во второй части**

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

**При наличии слов, обязательно требующих раскрытия (пояснения) значения, ставится тире:** Он всеми силами души всегда желал одного — быть вполне хорошим (Л. Т.); **В таких предложениях тире замещает пропущенный пояснительный союз (можно вставить а именно).** Пропуск союза может фиксироваться тире и в предложениях с достаточно определенными по значению словами, но нуждающимися в пояснении с точки зрения пишущего: Задача, поставленная перед отрядом, была трудная — до рассвета дойти до леса;

Примечание. В подобных случаях **при более подчеркнутом пояснении** может употребляться и **двоеточие**: Все они [письма] о главном: перестройке в нашей жизни (газ.); Настроение одно: скорее добраться до дома (газ.).